# SQLite install: path not recognized

Tags: javascript, node.js, sqlite

I installed SQLite with `npm install sqlite3 --build-from-source = sqlite3`, which ran without problems. However, when trying to run SQLite via command line with `sqlite3`, this command is not found. Error: `-bash: sqlite3: command not found`

When I run a script like this from the example below, it works OK.

Is there any path configuration missing for the `sqlite3` command to be recognized? After all, sqlite is installed and running.

Script test OK:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

var sqlite3 = require('sqlite3').verbose();  
var db = new sqlite3.Database('abcd');  

db.serialize(function() {
  db.run("create table if not exists user (id INT, dt TEXT)");

  var stmt = db.prepare("INSERT INTO user VALUES (?,?)");  
  for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {  

  var d = new Date();  
  var n = d.toLocaleTimeString();  
  stmt.run(i, n);  
  }  
  stmt.finalize();

  db.each("SELECT id, dt FROM user", function(err, row) {  
      console.log("User id : " + row.id, row.dt);  
  });  
});  

db.close();
```

Comment: npm is a tool for installing software packages prepared for nodejs in an environment where nodejs will find them.  It is not a tool for managing your system and installing other programs.  bash will search your $PATH to find an executable file whose name matches that given in the command. Perhaps npm built a sqlite3 executable for you, but it is not in your $PATH. If so you need to find it to run it. Perhaps npm built only the library for use from javascript/nodejs and did not build a standalone executable. What operating system are you using?

Comment: OK. This make sense...
My operating system is Linux Debian Jessie 8.6.
What can I do to run both, the bash scripts and make sqlite work by using the "$ sqlite3" command? Install in two ways?

Answer (score 0):

On Debian (Jessie, 8.6) I would run

```
apt-get install sqlite3
```

as root to install the [sqlite3](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/sqlite3) package that debian has provided.  This will place an executable file 'sqlite3' in /usr/bin, which is already in your $PATH.

This is one of the benefits of Debian as an operating system: they provide many well-made packages and the package management for your entire system.

Comment: Hello dsh. This was the first installation I did and it worked for running sqlite in bash. But when I run a script, like "./script_test.js", it doesn't work because sqlite is not found.

There is one other thing I haven't tried yet, but I'm guessing I'll have to install two packages, one via npm for scripts to work with nodejs and one via apt-get to work in bash. But I confess that I'm quite displeased with this idea of having two packages to do the same thing...

Comment: Yeah, the Debian `sqlite3` package is not a nodejs library/package, and will not be found by the nodejs import mechanism.  Each programming environment (nodejs, python, ruby, perl, etc.) will need its own layer to link to the libsqlite3.so library. Some of these are provided already by debian's package maintainers.  In fact, I just did a search and found [node-sqlite3](https://packages.debian.org/search?suite=stable&section=all&arch=any&searchon=names&keywords=sqlite+node) is already packaged. You could install that package and see if that meets your needs for nodejs-based programs.

Comment: Thank you. I've installed both packages and It's working for now. I still think is wrong, but I have no choice, so....